# jQuery UI accordion not working nested div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery accordion doesn't seem to work very well with nested div [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48fvz7st/) (*click on the load button*)

In the javascript I have added a select for the header element "h3"

```
 $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
     header: "h3",
     icons: icons,
    });
```

Full Javascript:

```
function simplate2(data, template) {
  return data.map(function(e) {
    return template.replace(/\{\{(\S+)\}\}/g, function(match, p1) {
      return e[p1]
    });
  }).join(' ');
}

var test101 = $('#test101'),
  query = {
    bid: 0815,
    f: 'FethStripeCard'
  },
  template = $('#template').html(),
  icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
  };

$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  $.post("/echo/json/", query, function(d) {

    var data = [{
      "id": "card_187wcdHV08ug7",
      "type": "Visa",
      "cardno": "**** 4242",
      "exp_month": 6,
      "exp_year": 2019
    }, {
      "id": "card_189KaFH",
      "type": "MasterCard",
      "cardno": "**** 4444",
      "exp_month": 5,
      "exp_year": 2017
    },{
      "id": "card_187wcdHV08ug7",
      "type": "Visa",
      "cardno": "**** 4242",
      "exp_month": 6,
      "exp_year": 2019
    },];

    test101.html(simplate2(data, template))
    /*.accordion({
     icons: icons
    });
    */
  });

  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
     header: "h3",
     icons: icons,

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
<div id="test101">
  <div id="template">

    <h3>{{type}} {{cardno}} exp{{exp_month}} / {{exp_year}}</h3>
    <div id="savedcard1-option">
      <div class="control-group">
        <form>
          <p class="card-type Visa card-type-amex"> {{type}} (Fee $0.20)</p>
          <input data-saved-card-id="{{id}}" type="hidden" class="addItemPo">
          <div class="controls">

            <button type="submit" class="stripe-button-el">Place my order</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="NewCardContainer">
    <h3>Pay with debit or credit card </h3>

    <form>

      <p class="card-type card-type-amex"> <span style="display:none">
     <span class="card-name"></span> (Fee £<span id="NewCardFee"></span>)</span>
      </p>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label for="NewCardNumber" class="control-label">Card Number</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input autocomplete="off" class="text text-large input-large" data-val="true" data-val-cardtypemustbevalid="Invalid card type" data-val-regex="Your card number must be 12-19 digits and cannot contain spaces" data-val-regex-pattern="^(\d{12,19})$" data-val-required="Card number is required"
          id="NewCardNumber" maxlength="19" name="card_accountNumber" placeholder="" required="required" title="Card Number" type="tel" value="">
          <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="card_accountNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          <div class="control-info">

            <input id="SaveCardCheckbox" type="checkbox" title="Save my card for quicker reordering" checked="">
            <label for="SaveCardCheckbox">Save my card for quicker reordering</label>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<button>Load</button>
```

This seem to ignore the first 3 generated `h3` tag and attach his  classes to the `h3` tag wrapper with the `NewCardContainer` div

The issue I am having is getting it to work for the other `h3` tag so that when the user clicks on the card info it will slide down nicely has shown in the jQuery-ui accordion example code

Comment: Please can you post your HTML as well.

Comment: @RhysO sorry I have updated the question

Comment: @RhysO this problem has been solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep it simple and follow the docs, stuff works.
Accordion should contain only `<h3>` (or other headers) followed by the content for that header. That's it.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07w55tyj/11/
Or view here:

```js
function simplate2(data, template) {
  return data.map(function(e) {
    return template.replace(/\{\{(\S+)\}\}/g, function(match, p1) {
      return e[p1]
    });
  }).join(' ');
}

var template = $('#template').html(),
  icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
  };

var data = [{
  "id": "card_187wcdHV08ug7",
  "type": "Visa",
  "cardno": "**** 4242",
  "exp_month": 6,
  "exp_year": 2019,
  "fee": 0.50
}, {
  "id": "card_189KaFH",
  "type": "MasterCard",
  "cardno": "**** 4444",
  "exp_month": 5,
  "exp_year": 2017,
  "fee": 0.50
}, {
  "id": "card_187wcdHV08ug7",
  "type": "Visa",
  "cardno": "**** 4242",
  "exp_month": 6,
  "exp_year": 2019,
  "fee": 0.50
}, ];

$('#accordion').prepend(simplate2(data, template))

$("#accordion").accordion({
  header: "h3",
  icons: icons,

});
```

```css
#template {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="template">
  <h3>{{type}} {{cardno}} exp{{exp_month}} / {{exp_year}}</h3>
  <div id="savedcard1-option">
    <div class="control-group">
      <form>
        <p class="card-type Visa card-type-amex"> {{type}} (Fee $0.20)</p>
        <input data-saved-card-id="{{id}}" type="hidden" class="addItemPo">
        <div class="controls">

          <button type="submit" class="stripe-button-el">Place my order</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Pay with debit or credit card </h3>

  <form>

    <p class="card-type card-type-amex"> <span style="display:none">
     <span class="card-name"></span> (Fee £<span id="NewCardFee"></span>)</span>
    </p>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="NewCardNumber" class="control-label">Card Number</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="text text-large input-large" data-val="true" data-val-cardtypemustbevalid="Invalid card type" data-val-regex="Your card number must be 12-19 digits and cannot contain spaces" data-val-regex-pattern="^(\d{12,19})$" data-val-required="Card number is required"
        id="NewCardNumber" maxlength="19" name="card_accountNumber" placeholder="" required="required" title="Card Number" type="tel" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="card_accountNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <div class="control-info">

          <input id="SaveCardCheckbox" type="checkbox" title="Save my card for quicker reordering" checked="">
          <label for="SaveCardCheckbox">Save my card for quicker reordering</label>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The issue with this approach is that if the cards e.g. visa, master is not already in existed then accordion doesn't kick in for `Pay with debit or credit card`. To test this just comment out `var `data

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. commenting out the data var leads to an error when trying to access it.. obviously that won't work. In any case, that is a different question than you asked. My answer just shows you how to properly deal with dynamic data in an accordion - do whatever you need with it, and also you should know about the `refresh` method on accordions if you want to dynamically change their contents

Comment: @anitshok the answer was for me to do this `if(typeof data !== "undefined")$('#accordion').prepend(Shopping.simplate2(carddata, template));`